# Analyse and order football league teams c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, std-pair

I'm trying to think of the best solution to display the winners of a football league in a very specific order.
The problem is the following:

You input the number of teams playing. Then you input the scores for all the teams in a matrix form ( mi,j = (x,y) would mean team i has scored x goals and team j has scored y).

The required output would be a ranked list of the teams with the following information: team number, team points, team goals done, team goals received. First would go the team with more points, if two teams have the same points the first one would be the team with best goals difference (done - received) and if that is the same the order would just be the number of the team. If you win you get 3 points and if you draw you get 1.

```
Sample input
4
0 0   1 0   2 1   0 2
2 2   0 0   3 3   1 3
1 1   1 2   0 0   3 2
1 0   0 1   2 3   0 0 
Sample output
4 9 10 8
3 8 12 12
1 8 6 7
2 8 9 10
```

It is a more complex problem than the ones I am used to deal with (which is great).
The problem I am having is I can't decide how to tackle the ordering system. I think the best would be to save the points, goals done and goals received in another matrix but then I don't know how I would order them. To analyse the scores I think I would do a draw/win/lose workflow with different functions to know what points I have to save, going first vertically through the matrix (skipping the main diagonal) and then horizontally.  How should I tackle the ordering system to then display the ranked table? Is another matrix the best solution to store the points, goals?

This is the easy code I have managed to do at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>

#include <utility>

using namespace std;



bool draw(const vector< vector<pair<int,int>> > &scores, int x, int y)  { // Is it a draw?

    if (scores[x][y].first == scores[x][y].second) return true;

    return false;

}



bool x_win(const vector< vector<pair<int,int>> > &scores, int x, int y) { // Is it a win for team x?

    if (scores[x][y].first > scores[x][y].second) return true;

    return false;

}



void input_pairs_in_matrix(vector< vector<pair<int,int>> > &scores, int n) { // input pairs

    int n1,n2;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            cin>>n1>>n2;

            pair<int,int> p = make_pair(n1,n2);

            scores[i][j] = p;

        }

    }

}



int main (){

    int n; cin >> n; // number of teams



    vector< vector<pair<int,int>> > scores(n,vector<pair<int,int>>(n)); //matrix of pairs



    input_pairs_in_matrix(scores,n);

}
```

PD: I am not looking for the whole solution as this is homework, but I am quite lost and would appreciate some tips/recommendations.

Comment: Tip: `if (p) return true; return false;` --> `return p;`.

Comment: Your matrix input doesn't make any sense. "mi, j" would have to be the inverse of "mj, i" and it isn't.

Comment: i think it can be different for home and away games ;-)

Comment: m(i, j) where i==j will be of no use but all others will make sense

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @molbdnilo , thanks :)

Comment: As @Msk pointed out, all "boxes" of the matrix are different matches! Sorry if it's not clear enough :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use `class` when coding in C++. They really help breaking your problem in small pieces that will be easier to understand, test and use.

For your problem, I would create a class team:

```
class Team
{
    public:
        unsigned int points;
        unsigned int goals_marked;
        unsigned int goals_received;
}
```

I put everything as public for a minimal answer, you may want a more complete class, maybe with `operator>>` to decode it, etc ... Then you can create an `operator<` on this type that will help you for your sort:

```
bool operator<(Team &lh, Team &rh)
{
    // return true if lh is less good than rh
}
```

Then sorting is just a matter of calling sort on a vector:

```
std::vector<Team> teams;
// Read your class and fill teams
std::sort(teams.begin(), teams.end());
```